# SQL Join where string is contained within another table field

Tags: sql, join

I have a couple of tables that I would like to join some how.

```
table 1
**Name** 
A Jones
J Brown
G Smith

Table 2
**fieldA**
~A Jones~G Smith~R Jones~
```

I want to join table 1 to 2 using the logic that where table 1.name is contained in table 2.fieldA.

therefore the result would be

```
A Jones
G Smith
```

Is this possible and how?

Sorry its SQL (2008)

Comment: Sorry Forgot to say its SQL (2008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also work for MSSQL

```
SELECT table_1.NAME
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.fieldA like '%' + table_1.NAME  + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *possible*, using something like this:

```
SELECT name
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.fieldA LIKE CONCAT('%~', table1.name, '~%')
```

Is is a bad idea, though, because it will be very slow (can't use indexes) and is not a stable database design. You would be better off normalizing your data.